# PetaPoco in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, orm, petapoco

How to commit changes done in DataGridView using PetaPoco ?  Something like :

```
namespace PetaPocoTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        PetaPoco.Database db = new PetaPoco.Database("PgConnection");

        IEnumerable<customers> allCustomers;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            allCustomers = db.Query<customers>("SELECT * FROM customers");
            mGrid.DataSource = allCustomers .ToList();            
        }

        private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db.Save("customers", "custumer_id", allCustomers);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: db.Save does not work. I get "The object doesn't have a property matching the primary key column name 'customer_id'"

Comment: I did try moving .ToList() above, and I still get "The object doesn't have a property matching the primary key column name 'customer_id'"

Answer (score 1):

Try my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39946768/2032608)

This is the simplest and easiest and can do what you want so far

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. I just wasted hours on something so obvious :\

```
namespace PetaPocoTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        PetaPoco.Database db = new PetaPoco.Database("PgConnection");

        IEnumerable<customers> allCustomers;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            allCustomers = db.Query<customers>("SELECT * FROM customers");
            mGrid.DataSource = allCustomers .ToList();            
        }

        private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             foreach (var a in allCustomers)
             {
               db.Save("customers", "custumer_id", a);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nop... this is not good! It works but it generates and executes UPDATE-s for all rows no matter if they are modified or not !

Comment: Micro ORMs generally don't track changes. You'll need to implement this yourself. I'd suggest you look for a modification event and flag each customer that gets changed as updated. Then upon save, only persist the customers which have changed