# PetaPoco update just modified records in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, petapoco

I have this code :

```
namespace PetaPocoTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        PetaPoco.Database db = new PetaPoco.Database("PgConnection");

        IEnumerable<customers> allCustomers;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            allCustomers = db.Query<customers>("SELECT * FROM customers");
            mGrid.DataSource = allCustomers .ToList();            
        }

        private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             foreach (var a in allCustomers)
             {
               db.Save("customers", "custumer_id", a);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

bat this updates all record, no matter if they are changed or not. 
So, my question is does anyone know how to update only changed records in petapoco ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it (eventually!) :

```
namespace PetaPocoTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        PetaPoco.Database db = new PetaPoco.Database("PgConnection");
        Dictionary<string, int> modRows = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bindingSource = db.Fetch<customers>("SELECT * FROM customers");
            mGrid.DataSource = bindingSource;            
        }

        private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           db.BeginTransaction();

               foreach (customers c in bindingSource)
               {
                   if (modRows.ContainsKey(c.id.ToString()))
                   {
                       db.Save("customers", "id", c);
                   }
               }

           db.CompleteTransaction();
        }

        private void mGrid_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int recId = ((customers)bindingSource.Current).id;

            if (!modRows.ContainsKey(recId.ToString()))
            {
               modRows.Add(recId.ToString(), recId);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It functions, but if anyone has better idea pls share!

Comment: Thank for this. This is so good seriously, Now we can simply save just db.Save(c) in foreach loop;

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way from me to do this by **db.BeginTransaction** on **Form_Load**

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        studentBindingSource.DataSource = db.Query<student>("SELECT * FROM student");
        db.BeginTransaction(); // Begin Transaction here
 }
```

On **Update** (**CellValueChanged**) just simply do **db.Save()** this doesn't commit yet because our transaction is not complete yet

```
 private void studentDataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        db.Save((student)studentBindingSource.Current);         
    }
```

And yes we can do **Insert** and **Delete** as well !!!

**Insert**

```
private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    student newStudent = new student
    {
        StudentName = "POCONEW"
    }
    studentBindingSource.Add(newStudent);
    db.Save(newStudent);
}
```

**Delete**

```
private void studentDataGridView_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = e.Row.Index; // We use Gridview row index instead because BindingSource.Current isn't work when user drag then deleting multiple row 
    db.Delete(studentDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].DataBoundItem as student);
}
```

Finally to **save change** we just do **db.CompleteTransaction()** 
*:Just a little note here after user press the Save Button if you don't close the form you have to call db.BeginTransaction() again if not everything user edit after this will be saved automatically because we don't have Transaction anymore*

```
private void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    db.CompleteTransaction();
    db.BeginTransaction(); // everything user edit after this will be saved automatically because we don't have Transaction anymore so we Begin it again
}
```

Comment: Catching exceptions without doing anything... bad idea :)

Comment: I still wonder what to do with it. If I show exception in message box do you think it's okay?

Comment: Sure not, just don't capture any exceptions there, what kind of exception do you want to avoid there?